# LibreOffice.org: Create new file from the command line

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

I love my command line. I love that I can type:

```
emacs non-existing-file.txt
```

and then `emacs` will start editing a file, that does not exist yet, but if I save it, it will be called `non-existing-file.txt`.

I am also quite fond of LibreOffice.org, but I have been unable to find a way to do the same trick, as I can with `emacs`:

```
lowriter non-existing.odt
```

will open LibreWriter, but it will not create the file. Instead it will complain that the file does not exist.

Is there a way that I from the command line can tell `lowriter` that I want to start a new file in this dir called `non-existing.odt`?

Comment: Inspired by [this comment](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40227#c21): `file='new.odt'; touch "$file" && libreoffice "$file" &`

Answer (score 2):

This feature was [requested for OpenOffice in 2002](https://bz.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=6077) and [for LibreOffice in 2011](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40227). As of now, neither project has implemented it.

A workaround is to create a blank file somewhere, and make a copy to create a new file. However this retains metadata such as the creation date from the original creation, so the result is not the same as creating a new document. Untested.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Create a new file if the argument does not exist. Do it only if there is a single
# argument and no option.
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
  case "$1" in
    -*) :;;
    *)
      if ! [ -e "$" ]; then
        basename="${1##*/}"
        case "$basename" in
          *.*)
            extension="${basename##*.}"
            cp ~/templates/default."$extension" "$1" || exit $?
        esac
      fi;;
  esac
fi

exec loffice "$@"
```

Converting an empty file works to create a text document (`.odt`), but not for other types of documents (with Libreoffice 5.1.6.2). I don't know why.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Create a new file if the argument does not exist. Do it only if there is a single
# argument and no option.
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
  case "$1" in
    -*) :;;
    *)
      if ! [ -e "$" ]; then
        basename="${1##*/}"
        case "$basename" in
          *.*)
            extension="${basename##*.}"
            empty_file=$(mktemp)
            unoconv -f "$extension" -o "$1" "$empty_file"
            rm -f "$empty_file"
        esac
      fi;;
  esac
fi

exec loffice "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem and solution

I was hoping that this would be an available, but it's not! I've recently been doing some job applications and manually creating a new CV/cover letter each time is tedious.

My solution was to create a directory called "base" where base a cv and cover letter are stored.

The bash script is then saved in a different 'scripts' folder elsewhere. It has been named 'apply.sh'.

### Code, examples, and file structure

An example of the creation of a new cv (or résumé) file:

```
apply.sh -r important_business_job

# creates...

~/.../your_job_applications_folder/cv_your_name_here_important_business_job.docx
```

The code I used is here:

```
# Takes a CV or cover letter and copies it with the role name changed.
#! /bin/bash

if getopts c:r: name
then
    case $name in
        c)OUTFILE= cover_letter_your_name_here_${OPTARG}.docx; INFILE=base/base_cover_letter.docx;;
        r)OUTFILE=cv_your_name_here_${OPTARG}.docx; INFILE=base/base_cv.docx;;
        *)echo "Invalid argument. Please select either 'r' for resume or 'c' for cover letter";;
    esac
    cp $INFILE $OUTFILE
else
    echo "Please select the type of file to create (either 'r' for resume or 'c' for cover letter)"
fi

shift $(($OPTIND -1))
```

File structure:

```
your_job_applications_folder
├── base
│   ├── base_cover_letter.docx
│   └── base_cv.docx
└── NEW_FILES_GO_HERE
```

### So, how does this relate to this post?

Using this same 'base' folder setup the code could be changed to copy a blank document from a base.docx document each time, effectively creating a new document. However, this may keep the original metadata...